# Unable to Track Email Click that Redirect to App

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have recently implemented an iOS universal link for our account. Since then link clicks that redirect to the App are not captured in tracking clicks. Salesforce support said that “Only links that take us to the web browser get tracked” is that true? Is there any workaround to capture clicks that redirects to App?

Comment: are the links wrapped, ie click.domain.com

Comment: Yes, links that are taking to the webpage are getting tracked and wrapped. but, when I click on my mobile and redirected to app are not tracked as clicks.

Comment: I never experienced this, but if it is true what Marketing Cloud Support is saying “Only links that take us to the web browser get tracked” a workaround could be, to link to a Cloud Page and redirect to the app from there, e.g. with AMPscript https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirect.htm

Comment: @BjörnSchubert. Yes I tried that. any link which is opened on iOS mobile is redirected to App. If we put mc-deep-link="false" it's not going to app.